# How to get Anaconda icon on Ubuntu 18 in application viewer

Tags: anaconda, data-science, ubuntu-18.04

I have to open anaconda each & every time by typing these commands 
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root 
$ anaconda-navigator

can you please tell me how to get the application icon in search application to open it directly

& I am also not able to add this to my favorites on launcher pad.

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 1):

Try making a desktop launcher for your anaconda icon.

check the path where you have installed your application by using `which myapplication_name`. you will get the installation path which you will need futher to make .desktop file.

```
 cd && vim anaconda.desktop
```

Copy the below code

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application
 Terminal=false
 Exec=/path/to/executable
 Name=Name of Application
 Icon=/path/to/icon
```

you can get the `**path/to/execution**` by which command navigate to `path/to/bin/anaconda.sh`

move your .desktop to `usr/share/application`

using below command

```
sudo mv anaconda.desktop usr/share/application
```

hope this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017284/cant-create-anaconda-shortcut-to-launch-from-desktop-on-ubuntu-17-10) helps you.